# How to represent a single element with attributes in XML schema?

Tags: xml, schema

I have an question about XML schema.

I've tried to explain a single element as below, but it have failed.

```
<parent-element>
    <check-element type="same">string value</check-element>
</parent-element>
```

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this question myself. ;)

```
<xs:complexType name="check-type">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="check"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="parent-element">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="check-element" type="target:check-type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```